# How to install a certain version of Apache Web-server to FreeBSD?

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd

I have a newly installed FreeBSD OS and I need to install an Apache web-server on it.  Need it to test some software.
But I need not the last version but exactly apache-2.2.17_1. How can I do that? I'm new to FreeBSD and actaully have no idea where to start with.

Comment: *Why* do you want an older version of Apache, with *known security holes* (see [the list of CVEs fixed in Apache since 2.2.17](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.2))?

Comment: @voretaq7, Really.I know that newer version mean less known bugs and security exploits. But I've asked about a certain version because I need it for tests. I thought it's kinda obvious from my question.

Comment: You say you need a specific version of the software, but you don't say ***WHY*** (which is important!). When someone asks me to point a loaded gun at their head I like to find out why they're asking for that.

Comment: Actually I did say why right in the second sentence of my question. For software tests. You know... QA and such.

Comment: You've still given me no technical reason a newer version of Apache (in the 2.2.x family, 100% ABI compatible) would not work, and I've frankly lost interest in extracting that information from you. I was looking for a way to help you avoid manually building/maintaining an out-of-date & known buggy piece of software, but it's your environment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation is that you install the version of Apache available in the ports collection (currently 2.2.22) - this includes a number of bug and *security* fixes over the version of Apache you mentioned.
Instructions on how to do this can be found [in the FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports.html), which I suggest you read [in its entirety](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/), especially if you are new to FreeBSD.  It will answer 99.9% of the questions you're likely to ask.

If you absolutely *require* a specific (older) version of Apache you can download the source from httpd.apache.org and build it manually.  Explaining the Apache build process is beyond the scope of a Q&A site, but [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) would be a good starting place to learn more.

Comment: So is there no other way other than building it from a source code? No kind of repository with older binaries?

Comment: @Regs Old software with known security problems isn't kept around for long, for what should be obvious reasons. You have some very odd requirements, it's going to be a bit uphill the whole way.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Not good but will spend some time to build it myself. But never had those kind of an issues with proprietary soft :\ Even if it wasn't in public downloads support were always sending me just a version I need. Ah well...